# Using jquery with Angular 2 via dotnet's SPA template

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using the dotnet SPA template for Angular. How do I use jquery in my components? When I do the following in my component, I don't get an alert:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("test");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you include the library for jquery and angular?
It seems you haven't include it in to your head tag.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
         alert("Hello World");
      });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <h3>Hello WORLD!</h3>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've included it in the _Layout.cshtml file but it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you look at the dev tools log? to know if there is some error pointing out?

Comment: No error in console. It is Angular2 and I am using the SPA template provided by dotnet, so the referencing of scripts is done somewhere else which I am not quite sure where!